# Using nparcomp with user-defined contrasts

Tags: r

I would like to test the hypothesis `H0: a2 - a1 = b2 - b1` on the following data:

**data.csv**

```
a1,a2,b1,b2
0.439,0.066,0.0,0.001
0.451,0.07,0.0,0.0
0.446,0.06,0.0,0.0
0.34,0.056,0.0,0.0
0.294,0.008,0.0,0.0
0.284,0.002,0.001,0.0
1.0,1.0,0.002,0.0
```

First, I tried ANOVA:

```
library(car)
data = read.csv('data.csv')
labels = factor(rep(c('a1','a2','b1','b2'), 
                c(nrow(data['a1']), nrow(data['a2']), nrow(data['b1']), nrow(data['b2'])))) 
x = C(labels, c(-1, 1, 1, -1), 1) 
y = c(data[['a1']], data[['a2']], data[['b1']], data[['b2']]) 
l = lm(y ~ x) 
a = Anova(l)
print(a$`Pr(>F)`)
```

which gives `p = 0.1891837`.

However, since I cannot assume that the data comes from a normal distribution, I would like to use a non-parametric test instead.  I tried using [nparcomp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nparcomp/nparcomp.pdf) with a user-defined contrast matrix:

```
library(nparcomp)
data = read.csv('data.csv')
x = factor(rep(c('a1','a2','b1','b2'), 
                c(nrow(data['a1']), nrow(data['a2']), nrow(data['b1']), nrow(data['b2'])))) 
y = c(data[['a1']], data[['a2']], data[['b1']], data[['b2']]) 
nparcomp(y ~ x, data=data.frame(x, y), type="UserDefined", contrast.matrix=t(matrix(c(-1, 1, 1, -1))))
```

This failed with the error:

```
Error in nparcomp(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x, y), type =
   "UserDefined",  :   Sums of positive contrast coefficients must be 1!
```

which I fixed by rescaling the contrast matrix to `t(matrix(c(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5)))`.  However, this failed with another error:

```
Error in logit.dev %*% cov.bf : non-conformable arguments
```

**What is the correct way to use nparcomp with user-defined contrasts?**

P.S. I am a newcomer to R, so apologies for the bad coding style.

Comment: The coding style isn't bad, but you have a lot of syntax errors.  In the first chunk of code, where you do ANOVA, what exactly are you trying to do between `library(car)` and `print(a$Pr(>F))`?

Comment: I read into a four-column data frame `data`; combine the columns into a concatenated vector `y`; create a factor `labels` of the same length as `y` labelling whether each element of `y` comes from a1, a2, b1, or b2; create a contrast, `x`, out of `labels` with contrast matrix `c(-1, 1, 1, -1)` (i.e. -a1 + a2 + b2 - b1 = 0); make a linear model `l` from `x` and `y` and calculate the ANOVA p-value from this model.  The code is loosely based on [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40958/).  It runs without any warnings, so I'm surprised you mention there are syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying that I'm not familiar with this particular area of statistics at all, so although my code does run without errors, my modification may have completely changed the design of what you are trying to test - let me know if this is the case. Anyways, I looked through the definition of `nparcomp` to see what was causing the first error, `Sums of positive contrast coefficients must be 1!` -

```
if (type == "UserDefined") {
        if (is.null(contrast.matrix)) {
            stop("Please eanter a contrast matrix!")
        }
        Con <- contrast.matrix
        rownames(Con) <- paste("C", 1:nrow(Con))
        for (rc in 1:nrow(Con)) {
            if (sum(Con[rc, ][Con[rc, ] > 0]) != 1) {
                stop("Sums of positive contrast coefficients must be 1!")
            }
        }
        colnames(Con) <- fl
}
```

In the case of your original `contrast.matrix` of `t(matrix(c(-1, 1, 1, -1)))` this evaluates to 2; whereas your second attempt of `t(matrix(c(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5)))` clearly evaluates to 1 in the above block of code (since it doesn't produce this error).

Your second error, `Error in logit.dev %*% cov.bf : non-conformable arguments`, seems to be arising from trying to multiply matrices of incompatible dimensions. I didn't trace the root of this particular error (the body of this function is pretty lengthy), but it gave me the idea to try passing `t(matrix(c(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5)))` as a symmetric matrix:

```
contrVec <- t(matrix(c(-1, 1, 1, -1)))
contrMat <- -1*(matrix(
  outer(contrVec,
        t(contrVec)),
  ncol=4)/2)
##
> contrMat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5
[2,]  0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.5
[3,]  0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.5
[4,] -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5
```

Passing this to `contrast.matrix` does not produce any errors, but as I've said, I am unfamiliar with this particular procedure / function, so I may have completely changed the hypothesis you are trying to test. Here's the full code:

```
library(car)
library(nparcomp)
##
data <- data.frame(
  a1=c(.439,.451,.446,
       .340,.294,.284,1.00),
  a2=c(.066,.07,.06,.056,
       .008,.002,1.00),
  b1=c(rep(0.0,5),
       .001,.002),
  b2=c(.001,
       rep(0.0,6)))
##
x <- factor(
  rep(names(data),
      each=nrow(data)))
##
y <- c(data[['a1']], data[['a2']], 
       data[['b1']], data[['b2']])
##
contrVec <- t(matrix(c(-1, 1, 1, -1)))
contrMat <- -1*(matrix(
  outer(contrVec,
        t(contrVec)),
  ncol=4)/2)
##
nprce <- nparcomp(
  y ~ x, 
  data=data.frame(x, y), 
  type="UserDefined", 
  contrast.matrix=contrMat)
##
> summary(nprce)

 #------------Nonparametric Multiple Comparisons for relative contrast effects----------# 

 - Alternative Hypothesis:  True relative contrast effect p is less or equal than 1/2 
 - Estimation Method: Global Pseudo ranks 
 - Type of Contrast : UserDefined 
 - Confidence Level: 95 % 
 - Method = Logit - Transformation 

 - Estimation Method: Pairwise rankings 

 #---------------------------Interpretation--------------------------------------------# 
 p(a,b) > 1/2 : b tends to be larger than a 
 #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------# 

 #----Data Info-------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  Sample Size
1     a1    7
2     a2    7
3     b1    7
4     b2    7

 #----Contrast--------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
      a1   a2   b1   b2
C 1 -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5
C 2  0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.5
C 3  0.5 -0.5 -0.5  0.5
C 4 -0.5  0.5  0.5 -0.5

 #----Analysis--------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  Comparison Estimator Lower Upper Statistic   p.Value
1        C 1     0.429 0.345 0.517 -1.593593 0.1110273
2        C 2     0.571 0.483 0.655  1.593593 0.1110273
3        C 3     0.571 0.483 0.655  1.593593 0.1110273
4        C 4     0.429 0.345 0.517 -1.593593 0.1110273

 #----Overall---------------------------------------------------------------------------# 
  Quantile   p.Value
1 1.959966 0.1110273

 #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Comment: Using the same contrast for each (e.g. `t(matrix(replicate(4, c(-0.5, 0.5, 0.5, -0.5)), ncol=4))`) also works fine.  This is a strange quirk.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it worked out for you. I agree, it does seem a little strange, and I was surprised that the authors did not include an example using `UserDefined` contrasts in the help file.